# When sharing a Dropbox file via a shared link, it is possible to hide the file meta data sidebar by default?

Tags: dropbox

When sharing a Dropbox file via a shared link, it is possible to hide the file meta data sidebar by default?

I've noticed that the URL does not change whether the sidebar is opened/closed so you can not hide the sidebar by editing the URL.

Please see attached markup for further information.

[image: marked up screenshot of shared file in Dropbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I've found to do it is to replace the parameter at the end of the URL `dl=0` with `raw=1`.

So `https://www.dropbox.com/s/seiaurp9wefjksadjvpisautp9ojsdipf/myfile.pdf?dl=0`

Would become `https://www.dropbox.com/s/seiaurp9wefjksadjvpisautp9ojsdipf/myfile.pdf?raw=1`